What is this enclosed space that projects out of the house called?

Source
What do you call that enclosed space sticking out of the house in the US?

When it is on the rear of a house, as it is in your picture, in the US it is often called a "mudroom".

Not directly relevant, because it's BrE rather than AmE, but on this side of the pond many of us call that a porch.

Would a porch in the UK be narrow like that, and jut out perpendicularly from the house? In the US, a porch's long side runs parallel to a house wall, not perpendicular to it.

Off topic, but you can find lots of pictures of porches on Wikipedia. It describes a range of things, open and closed, squarish and long.

My own house has a front porch similar to that pictured, except it doesn't project so far away from the main building, and the front door faces forward. It's a "self-build" house that I worked on a bit as a teenager helping my father in the 60s. None of the houses in the group had a front porch when first built, but every single one of the dozen in the group has added something similar over the decades. And as it happens, the tumbledown house we lived in before "the new house" had a (much bigger) "open archway" rear porch. (So I know porches! :)

...that older rear porch only covered about 1/3rd the width of the building, but if it had extended across the full width (with no actual walls on the side furthest from the main building, just archways and support piers) we'd probably have called it a veranda.

@FumbleFingers - The poster is not asking what that is called in British English.  Why the unnecessary and off topic comments (3)?  It has derailed the entire comment section.  Is the comment section a place where and your friends can compare BrE and AmE?  Someone even upvoted the self-proclaimed not directly relevant comment.  Nepo buddies?

Question definitely needs more details: is the structure at the front, back, or side of the house? Where in the US is it situated? What is inside the structure? What is it used for? What is outside it? What style of architecture? (For instance a mudroom is typically not at the main entrance and contains footwear and similar storage, often a bench, sometimes a sink, etc; while an entryway would be at the front but more minimally furnished; a garden room faces a garden and is used for sitting in, etc.)

@StuartF - The question doesn't need any additional information.  It's a picture of a mudroom.  If I see a picture of an igloo, I don't need to know where it's located or what it's made of; it's an igloo.

Just to be mischievous, in British English, which was not asked for, I would call that thing that's all walled in, with its own outside door, a vestibule. A porch, to me, is open on at least one of its three sides.

In the U.S. that small room is often called a mudroom.  I have only ever heard it called that, however, in places that get muddy, the midwestern, eastern, and southern U.S.  Generally it serves as a place to remove your coat, boots, and shoes.
I'm not sure if they would call it a mudroom in Arizona.  Would there even be such a room in Arizona?

The full OED says mud room typically occurs about 0.05 times per million words in modern written English, whereas porch typically occurs about nine times per million words in modern written English. That's a pretty big difference.

I am not an AmEng speaker but I do like interior design, and I have heard of and seen what mudrooms are. +1

A porch, for me, is an open area attached to the long side of the house that has a porch roof  held up by poles or covered by a canopy. It is a place where you can sit and eat outside. The floor area will often be paved. It is not a mudroom.

The full (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary "prevalence" figures I cited were from their entry for mud room (first recorded 1950), where the main entry itself is two words, as are 3 of the 4 cited written instances (the other one is hyphenated). Their definition is A small vestibule, spec. one in which wet or muddy footwear may be left as one enters a house. And I'm not going looking for details, but it's my recollection that not all Inuits are happy about the way the word igloo is used in other languages.

@FumbleFingers a porch is usually open and exposed to the outdoors. If it is enclosed, it would be enclosed with glass or screens, so the outdoors is still visible. I would not call any fully-enclosed area in front of a house a porch.

@Esther: Can we not just agree that certain words have different meanings to different people? I grew up in my house, and I've ended up moving back into it in later life. Within a few years of my father building the house, he added what everyone here has always called a porch - where the only significant difference between my porch and OP's picture is that my front door faces forward, not sideways. You can call anything whatever you like, so long as the people you interact with understand you. But so can I, and in my case they definitely do!

@FumbleFingers - We can agree that things are called different things by different people.  You, for example, have decided to answer a question about AmE with answer that applies to BrE, thereby diluting the actual comments that are trying to answer the poster's question.  And sill you beat the drum.

@FumbleFingers I'm pretty sure the reason for the relative popularity of the word "porch" is that many more houses have an open area in front of them than have an enclosed one (at least where I live, that is almost universally the case), rather than because an enclosed structure is called a "porch." Especially in the US, it most certainly isn't.

@EllieK I live in the US and might easily call such an area a porch. My house has an exposed porch on the front; my neighbor's house has an enclosed space in the same position for the same purpose, an indoor porch. My grandparents' house had a rear room with a carpet and everyone called that a porch. Yeah it's always been a little odd to me, no I couldn't tell you how the people I was emulating drew the distinction, but everything FumbleFingers has said seems accurate, so you can at least stop being rude about it.

@the-baby-is-you - Before 1980 that structure would almost always be called a porch.    Starting in about 1980 in the U.S and somewhere around the mid 1990's in the UK, these small rooms started to be called mudrooms, a more descriptive name based on how they were often used.  If you still want to call them porches, feel free.  You are entirely correct to do so.  I am just trying to give learners the modern terminology for that structure in the U.S.  Every mudroom is indeed a porch, if someone wants to insist it so.
